# Connection string for a SQL Server database sitting on a local drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I'm trying to test an application and I need some friends to test it for me who live elsewhere. I've got VS2010 installed on a WinXP machine and I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on the same computer. Both applications are installed on the C:\ drive of the WinXP computer.

I gave my IP address to my friends. They can see the website, however they can't access any of the data.

Is there some standard connection string I would have to access this data, or is this one of those "I have to sit in front of your computer to know what's wrong"-type things?  The connection string I currently have in my web.config is:

```
<add name="MySiteConn" 
     connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: What makes you think the connection string is the problem? The website sits on your computer so it doesn't matter where the end user is.

Comment: If the whole site loads and runs but the users can't get to the data, and I can get to the data when I run it through localhost (i.e. through VS2010, not the Internet), what else could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access via VS but not via the website, its probably because your (I assume) IIS account doesn't have access to the database.  You are using integrated security.

It might be easier to add a user and password to the connection string, then give that user access to your DB and tables etc.  I would just use the IIS user, but there are probably best practices in this case you can follow.  Since you are hosting it all on XP I assume security isnt your top priority.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection isn't the problem (if you have VPN set up or whatever means of connection), then it might be your SQL Server is not configured to get connection from other computers. Make sure you allow other connection to SQL Server, check SQL Configuration Manager and configure Firewall Inbound Rules. Otherwise I'd go to Elizabeth's answer.